# Firebase 404.html in other directory other than root

Tags: firebase

I have my custom 404 page at directory `/404/index.html`. But firebase requires it to be at the root directory and named `404.html`. I have tried rewriting it the custom location but it doesn't seem to work. May I know if it is not possible to define own custom location where the 404 page resides?

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "rewrites": [ {
        "source": "/404.html",
        "destination": "/404/index.html"
    } ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Try `"source": "404.html"`?

Comment: Just tried, same thing. Only when navigating to `www.mysite.com/404`, do I get my custom 404 page. If I navigate to `www.mysite.com/somePath/notExist`, I get the default firebase 404 page

Comment: From the docs it doesn't look possible. Any particular reason why you don't want 404.html in root?

Comment: Not really, as I am using a Jekyll theme and it generates it in a different location. I shall probably find a way to customize the theme to generate it to fit firebase's location. Worse case, I shall just write a post script built to copy the file over instead.